# Are hardware settings on-topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I would like to ask about nVidia GPU's, G-Sync monitors and in-game framerate capping. In this instance, specifically for Destiny 2.

I've had a read of Superuser on-topic advise, and [it prohibits video game questions](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). However it would be relevant as a hardware specific question.

Then on the other hand, it is about gaming, but isn't gaming specific. Although Arqade [does say about no hardware recommendations](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Where does this type of question best fit on the Stack Exchange network? Would it be closed for opinion based? As you might argue the answer might change per-game, or users may disagree based on their own experience.

Should I phrase my question more towards a game specific example for Arqade, but a more generic hardware performance slant for Superuser?

My expectation would be an answer including links and excerpts from reputable testing. Such as Linus Tech Tips, or similar tech focused content.

Comment: I don't think there's enough detail here to come to a reliable conclusion. Could you add the title of your question (and some of the body if the title is unclear as to what you want?). "in-game framerate capping" *suggests* it should be asked here, but the request for reputable testing makes me hesitate.

Comment: Posting to Arqade, I would frame it as Destiny 2, with my monitor model specifically and performance of the game. However I wondered if I specialised the question too much it wouldn't be as helpful to other people.

Answer (score 5):

I think it actually fits both sites:

- Capping framerates is a way to handle a problem that is **caused by a hardware-specific property**, that
- (at the moment) **only really happens to matter in video gaming** (or CGI in general).

Whether or not it becomes apparent through video games, the problem lies with the refresh rate of monitors, and curbing that framerate is a way to cope with it.
For gamers it's especially interesting, however, since it affects gameplay (and physics in some cases (Havok?)).

Answer (score 0):

For a question this specific in PC gaming, the official game support channels are your best bet. Whether that would be the developer, publisher, or their respective forums depends on the game. 
My main impression is that most people would be better served getting direct answers from people that have already tested hundreds of hardware combinations for their game.

In this case: [Destiny 2 Known Issues and Support](https://www.bungie.net/en/Help/Article/46180) or [Destiny 2 PC Support Forums](https://www.bungie.net/en/Forums/Topics?pNumber=0&tg=Help%20PCSupport)

My opinion for console gaming would probably be different since hardware *mostly* comes in only one or two variations per console generation.